# Reformulating an integral for lower compute during repeated evaluation across different constants?

Tags: calculus

I am doing Bayesian computing where my model involves computing a definite integral over $x$ of the function $f(x,y,z)$ repeatedly for many combinations of values of $y$ & $z$. $f()$ has the form:
$$
f(x,y,z) = a(x) \times e^{b(x) \times y + c(x) \times z}
$$

Unfortunately $a(x)$, $b(x)$ & $c(x)$ are not analytically expressible and instead are derived empirically at finely-resolved values for x. So far I've been computing the integral by numeric approximation, and this yields very slow computation amidst the Bayesian MCMC sampling algorithm having to re-compute everything for each new candidate values for $y$ and $z$.

Is there any reformulation of the integral that would permit pre-computation of any values conditional on only $x$ to reduce subsequent compute of the integral for new values of $y$ and $z$?

Comment: $f(x,y,z) = a(x)\times g(x)^{y \times z}$, where $g(x) = e^{b(x)\times c(x)}$. How about Gaussian quadrature: pre-compute $g(x_i)$ and $a(x_i)$ at a large number of points ($n$) and their corresponding weights ($w_i$), then compute $\sum_{i=1}^nw_i\times a(x_i)\times g(x_i)^{y \times z}$ for each new set of values for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Are you sure about the identity you propose? I don't think $g(x)^{(y\times z)}$ is equal to $e^{((b(x)\times y) + (c(x)\times z))}$

Comment: The formulation in my first comment is not correct. I misread the $+$ for $\times$. Rather, it would be $f(x,y,z)=a(x)\times g(x)^y\times h(x)^z$, where $g(x)=e^{b(x)}$ and $h(x)=e^{c(x)}$. The basic idea remains the same, though.

Comment: You could consider $a$ as a probability distribution, and then try to expand $\langle e^{by+cz}\rangle$ in a cumulant expansion to the first few orders. Maybe that is accurate enough.

Comment: @user619894, could you possibly expand on your suggestion? a() has a form that is probably interpretable as a pdf if I had empirical data a(x) across a wider range of x values, but in the range I’m integrating it’s fairly monotonic; I think that just means expressing it as a truncated pdf? I think I know how to do that, but then I don’t follow how that’s useful and combines with the latter part of your suggestion, which I don’t quite follow itself.

Answer (score 1):

My idea was to calculate a few moments: $\langle b^{m}c^{n}\rangle$
where $\langle f\rangle\stackrel{def}{=}\int dxa(x)f(x)$ and then
write $\langle e^{yb+zc}\rangle=e^{F(y,z)}$where $F=\log\langle e^{yb+zc}\rangle\approx\log\left(\langle1\rangle+y\langle b\rangle+z\langle c\rangle+\cdots\right)$
which is the cumulant expansion. Evaluating say to order 4 will take
about 10-20 evaluations of $\langle b^{m}c^{n}\rangle$but then you
can substitute reasonable values of $y,z$ and read off a good approximation
of the integral with $O(1)$evaluations.

If $y,z$ are very large, don't use the cumulant expansion, rather, note that $e^{yb}$ for large $y$ can be treated by Laplace's method, that is, considering the local maxima in $x$. Hopefully, with small values of $y,z$ approximated by the cumulant expansion and the large by Laplace's method, you can get good coverage of the domain.